# Installing Spacy for GPU training of Transformer

Tags: python, gpu, spacy, spacy-transformers

I installed also the CudaToolkit, and cuDNN.

I have the following

```
GPU:
| NVIDIA-SMI 531.68                 Driver Version: 531.68       CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                      TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 T...  WDDM | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   43C    P8                9W /  N/A|      0MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have been trying to install spacy with the following instructions on a couple of posts on the site and used

```py
pip install spacy[cuda121]
```

I get a warning that spacy 3.5.2 does not detect or support CUDA version 12.1.

I manage to get tensorflow to detect the GPU and when I run the following:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print('Num GPUs Available: ', len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

It detects 1 GPU.
I also ran:

```py
pip install cudy
```

I am wondering if there is something wrong with setup or if I doing something wrong. Any support would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `pip install -U 'spacy[cuda-autodetect]'` as shown in the install quickstart? https://spacy.io/usage#installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [`installation`](https://spacy.io/usage#installation) documentation and seeing the `warning` that you got, it seems that `spaCy` **does not** currently support `CUDA 12.1`. The installation guide is misleading because you can select the version of `CUDA` and there is a version for `CUDA 10.2, 11.0+`. Which suggests that anything above 11.0 is supported. However, that is not the case.

Here is what I mean by the installation guide being misleading:
[image]

Your best bet would be to downgrade your version of `CUDA` to `CUDA 11.8`. If you're looking for the `CUDA 11.8` links on the nvidia website:

- https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.8.0/
- https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-8-0-download-archive

Here is a GitHub discussion that talks about which version of `CUDA` should be used with both `spaCy` and `pytorch` after the release of `CUDA 12.1`:

- https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/12353